# Check message size in Python gRPC

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc

Is it possible to check the size of a gRPC message in Python before attempting to send it?

It would be useful when batching together smaller messages/requests client-side to ensure that the message size limit isn't exceeded.

Only current way I know of doing this is to assemble a message, attempt to send it, then retry with several smaller messages if a message size limit error is raised.

Comment: The ByteSize() method should return the message size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Protocol Buffers for your messages, I believe the `ByteSize()` method would be the right way to determine the serialized size of a message ([as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896685/check-message-size-in-python-grpc#comment74828796_43896685)).